# How to specify the size of radiobuttons inside of a radio box in wxPython 4.0.3

Tags: python, radio-button, wxpython

wxPython version: 4.0.3

I want to make my radio buttons in the radiobox 3-5 times larger in diameter than there are on an image below.

I have checked:

- https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.RadioBox.html
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wxpython/wx_radiobutton_radiobox.htm

I have tried:

- `rbox = wx.RadioBox(self.panel, size = wx.Size(100, 100))`
- `rbox(wx.Font(self.xs_font,wx.DEFAULT,wx.NORMAL,wx.NORMAL))`

all of this only changes the size of the field with radiobuttons but not actual radiobuttons

But It seems I cannot change the size of buttons

my code:

```
    rbox = wx.RadioBox(self.panel, size = wx.Size(100, 100),choices = ['off','on'],majorDimension = 1, style = wx.RA_SPECIFY_ROWS|wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
    sizer.Add(rbox , pos=(14, 8), span=(2,4), flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTER, border=5)
    rbox.Bind(wx.EVT_RADIOBOX,self.ToggleRBox)
    rbox.SetFont(wx_m_font)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. wx does not allow you to change the size of the buttons, only the window they are in. From the documentation:

> size (wx.Size) – Window size. If wx.DefaultSize is specified then a default size is chosen.

Maybe try tkinter? It also doesn't allow you to control the size of the button itself, but you can make the entire contents into a button using `indicatoron=0` which you *can* control the size of. Hope that helps.

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
var=IntVar()
R1=Radiobutton(root, text='Off', variable=var, value=1, height=10, width=20
               indicatoron=0)
R1.pack( anchor = W )
R2=Radiobutton(root, text='On', variable=var, value=2, height=10, width=20
               indicatoron=0)
R2.pack( anchor = W )
label=Label(root)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @valentyn Yes, it's a different package. [Tkinter Documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#module-tkinter) I looked through the wx documentation and couldn't find what you were looking for. I have a bit of experience with tkinter so I came up with this "near-solution" using what I knew. Thanks for accepting my answer!

Comment: @ dissemin8or you did provide a very good answer to my original question. Though it didn't help me to solve my problem, you pointed out that the current implementation of wxPython doesn't support a change in the size of the buttons.